# MSP430 Terminate timer_A in UP mode

Tags: c, msp430

Using embedded programming via CCS, MSP430F6736A

Need to know, if there is any way to stop Timer in UP mode(ie Timer_A).

In my app I´m using Timer_A in UP mode and register TA1CCR0 is toggling LED on/ off for a specific time. 0.5s LED- ON, 1 sec LED- OFF. After few minutes(for example 2 minutes==120 sec) i need to terminate the application. I need to stop timer and interrupt. Is there any way  how to break counting timer after these 120 seconds and get out of interrupt??

One way may be forbid the interrupts but timer will still be counting. I need to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

```
TACTL = MC_0;
```

will stop the timer.